# Pourquoi dit-on "en pratique" ?

Tags: usage

Pourquoi dit-on

> en pratique on dit ça

et non pas

> dans la pratique

par exemple ?

J'ai l'impression que les deux doivent pourvoir se dire, pourtant l'usage fait que l'on dit le plus souvent "en pratique".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans ce sens de *pratique* On peut distinguer :

**A/** La *pratique* en tant que confrontation à la *théorie*

C'est encore à dire en tant que concept abstrait. Et donc, d'idée **générale** de réalité. Dans ce cas, on utilise généralement : *en*.

***En*** théorie la vitesse maximale est celle de la lumière. **En** pratique, c'est peut-être différent.

En pratique = Dans la réalité (en général)

**B/** La *pratique* en tant que mise en œuvre d'un processus **particulier** (de fabrication, de mesure, de divertissement...).

En ce sens, il se confronte à une notice d'utilisation, une opinion répandue... Dans ce cas, on utilise généralement : *dans*, *dans la pratique* étant alors synonyme de : *à l'usage*. *Suivant mon expérience personnelle*. (et donc **particulière**)... dans la pratique... de ce truc en particulier.

*D'après le mode d'emploi, la publicité, ce tournevis dévisse absolument tout. Dans la pratique, c'est assez différent.*

---

<sup>Pour finir avec un bon mot dont j'ai oublié l'auteur : *La différence entre la théorie et la pratique ? En théorie, il n'y en a pas. En pratique, c'est différent.* :-)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Les deux, *en pratique* et *dans la pratique* existent mais ne s'emploient pas dans les mêmes cas.

*En pratique* veut dire « concrètement, dans l'exécution (opposé à *en théorie* » (*Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*), 
c'est synonyme des adverbes *pratiquement* et *concrètement* (qui s'opposent à théoriquement).

> En pratique, il est impossible de décrire l'état  initial de l'atmosphère avec suffisamment de précision pour pouvoir prévoir son évolution réelle de manière univoque. ([Météo France](http://www.meteofrance.fr/activites-recherche/faire-progresser-la-prevision-saisonniere/meilleure-previsibilite-tropiques))

*Dans la pratique* veut dire dans l'exercice de la vie quotidienne, dans le domaine de l'expérience quotidienne.

> Ces difficultés dans la pratique de pratique et de ses dérivés vous ont été rappelées à toutes fins... utiles. [Druide](https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/difficultes-pratiques).